# How to set VSCode debug console foreground color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

I've tried these, but none of them seem to work:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "consoleView.foreground":"#000",
        "debug.console.foreground": "#000",
        "debugConsole.foreground" : "#000",
        "debugConsole.infoForeground" : "#000",
        "debugConsole.warningForeground" : "#000",
        "debugConsole.errorForeground" : "#000",
        "debugConsole.sourceForeground" : "#000",
}
```